# Group By Unique Values and get Total for Each

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to count the number of occurrences of specific values within documents. I have documents that are structured like so:

```
  id: ObjectID("ABC123")
StoreItems: Array
    0: Object
        Type: "Apple"
        Color: "Green"
        Size: "Small"
        Weight: "5"
    1: Object
        Type: "Orange"
        Color: "Orange"
        Size: "Small"
        Weight: "8"
    2: Object
        Type: "Grapes"
        Color: "Green"
        Size: "Small"
        Weight: "8"
```

When I use the following it is only giving me the total count of the grouping and not for each specific Type:

```
[
    {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$StoreItems'
        }
    }, {
        '$match': {
            'StoreItems.Color': 'Green'
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': 'Type', 
            'Count': {
                '$sum': 1
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I want to get a result: `Apples: 1, Grapes:3`

But, I'm only getting a result: `Type: 4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the way you're building the `_id` for `$group` statement. Currently it is a static value `Type` while you need a reference to `StoreItems.Type` (starts with dollar):

```
{
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$StoreItems.Type', 
        'Count': {
            '$sum': 1
        }
    }
}
```